# In a RecyclerView adapter, how do I modify an onClickListener inside an activity

Tags: android, callback, android-recyclerview

In my main activity (`CreatePhotostoryActivity`), I have this method:

```
public void showEditField(Moment oldMoment, final int index){
    listRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    editCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    saveCancelNavbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    momentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    photoStoryNavbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(oldMoment.photoUri).into(displayPhoto);

    imageCaption.setText("");


    imageCaption.setText(oldMoment.caption);

    backIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeEditMoment();
        }
    });

    saveText.setText("Save Moment");

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateMoment(imageCaption.getText().toString(), index);
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeEditMoment();
        }
    });
}
```

I call `showEditField` in the `onBindViewHolder` method of my adapter like this:

```
final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder= (RecyclerView.ViewHolder)momentViewHolder;
((MomentViewHolder) momentViewHolder).momentCaption.setText(moments.get(i).caption);
Picasso.with(mContext).load(moments.get(i).photoUri).into(((MomentViewHolder) momentViewHolder).displayPhoto);

((RecyclerView.ViewHolder) momentViewHolder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mContext instanceof CreatePhotostoryActivity) {
            ((CreatePhotostoryActivity) mContext).showEditField(moments.get(position), position);

            // this is what I want to implement
            saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
                holder.momentCaption.setText(moments.get(position).caption);
                holder.momentPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.momentCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            });

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
                holder.momentPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.momentCaption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            })
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Of course, the `saveButton` and `cancelButton` onClickListeners inside `onBindViewHolder` are not working and that's what I'm trying to do. I also want to keep the methods called in the actual onClickListeners in the `showEditField` method. Basically, I want to "add" to `saveButton` and `cancelButton` onClickListeners from the adapter while maintaining its original functionality in the activity.

Edit: `saveButton` and `cancelButton` are only defined in the activity, but not in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

create  an interface in your Adapter

```
public interface customButtonListener {
     void onButtonClickListner(int position, View view,int pos);
}
```

and a method

```
public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;
    }
```

then declare a variable in the adapter

```
private customButtonListener customListner;
```

then set click listeners for your buttons in adapter

```
 holder.saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                    int pos=1;
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, view,pos);
                }

            }
        });
 holder.cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                    int pos=2;
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, view, pos);
                }

            }
        });
```

then in your `CreatePhotostoryActivity` implement `YourAdapter.customButtonListener`
and then do the following:

```
yourAdapterobj.setCustomButtonListner(CreatePhotostoryActivity.this);
 @Override
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position, View view, int pos) {
       if(pos==1) {
          //code for save button

       }
        else if(pos==2){
         //code for cancel button

       }

    }
```

Comment: Where do I put these?

`holder.momentCaption.setText(moments.get(position).caption);`
`holder.momentPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
`holder.momentCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: `saveButton` and `cancelButton` are only defined in the activity

Comment: You can get reference of the buttons in adapter using
`Button saveButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);`

Comment: What about the part where I'm setting the visibility of `momentPlaceholder` and `momentCaption`? Do I put them in `saveButton` and `cancelButton` onClick listeners in my adapter?

Comment: In my activity, `showEditField` has an onClick listener method for `saveButton`, and it contains this statement: `updateMoment(imageCaption.getText().toString(), index)`. I want it to still perform that action. In my adapter, `saveButton` has another onClick listener that sets the visibility of `momentCaption` and `momentPlaceholder`. Will those two onClick listeners conflict with each other?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `view` in `customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, view, pos);` be `v` instead?

Comment: in your Activity add
`@Override
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position, View view, int pos) {
       if(pos==1) {
          //code for save button

       }
        else if(pos==2){
         //code for cancel button

       }

    }`
to your `showEditField` method and remove the click listeners that u had set previously

Comment: yes, it is  `customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, v, pos);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158390/discussion-between-bargain23-and-aarif-aslam).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `RecyclerViewItemOnClickListener` which implements `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`
Check the below code snippets -

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;  
import android.view.GestureDetector;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;  
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {  
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }
}
```

Using it in code is very simple. Just add an item touch listener of this class to the RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // TODO Handle item click
      }
    })
);
```

Comment: Do i put the item touch listener in the activity?

Comment: `momentCaption` and `momentPlaceHolder` are only accessible in the adapter.

Comment: Yes you have to attach it to your RecyclerView